# Is it possible to have your Pokemon get out of its Pokeball and follow you?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

In other Pokémon games, your Pokemon might walk behind you. How do you make your Pokémon get out of its Pokéball and make it follow you?

Pokemon do need exercise you know...

Answer (score 12):

This is **only** possible in *Pokémon Yellow* (Pikachu only), and *Heart Gold*/*Soul Silver* (The first Pokémon in your party), where your Pokémon follow you automatically.

There's also a special park on Platinum and a side-quest on Black/White 2, but these don't count as "walking Pokémon".

Also in the side games *Pokémon Ranger* and *Pokémon Mystery Dungeon* games, Pokémon can be outside with you in most places.

Edit: Pokémon are also allowed to be out on games such as Let's Go Pikachu and Eevee, or Sword and Shield on the DLC content's Islands.

[**Sources**](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Walking_Pok%C3%A9mon)

Comment: Note that in HG/SS, if the Pokémon is too big (eg Kyogre), he won't follow you inside the buildings (so that he won't explode them)!You can also see his shinyness when he's following you and some event are available only when he follows you (eg the golden leaves).

Comment: This is also allowed in Pokemon Let's Go Games, with your starter Pikachu/Eevee and any other Pokemon in your party of your choice. These games came out after this answer and question were posted.